# MSSQL How to copy data from one table to another with a condition

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm trying to update table a with data from some of the columns in table b. Column names are matching in both tables, cannot figure out the syntax, can anyone help?

This is what I want to do (expressed out-of-syntax):

**UPDATE table_a
SET table_a.col1 = table_b.col1, table_a.col2 = table_b.col2
WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id**

Maybe (probably) I would need some kind of JOIN-clause, but I haven't gotten my head around those yet.... :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can update your table using a JOIN of the two tables:

```
UPDATE table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id
SET a.col1 = b.col1, a.col2 = b.col2
```

I see you are on MYSQL. Not sure if the version above works. If not, try:

```
UPDATE table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b
SET a.col1 = b.col1, a.col2 = b.col2
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Actually I'm on MSSQL. The MERGE thing works fine, getting "incorrect syntax near 'a' when trying your first solution"

Comment: Don't know why you get a syntax error. As far as I can see, it should work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bFjgYEtrD2HHi7s91fwyc/0

Edit: Sorry. I read that wrong the whole time. MSSQL != MYSQL. My fault. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found it myself... :-)

MERGE (without using the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause)is the answer to my problem.

My solution:

**MERGE INTO table_a
USING table_b
ON a.id=b.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
col1 = b.col1, col2 = b.col2;**